# PhpStorm causes Docker bind mount to freeze

Tags: docker, docker-compose, phpstorm, docker-volume

### Setup

I have a PHP project based on Drupal and I use docker-compose to test it locally.

In `docker-compose.yaml` I have a bind mount:

```
volumes:
  - ./modules/custom/test_module:/opt/drupal/web/modules/custom/test_module
```

Everything works fine, I see the files in container and when I edit them locally they get updated in container as well.

### Issue

When I edit those files using PhpStorm (v. 2021.1) the folder in container freezes immediately. If I open a terminal to container and execute `ls` in that folder, it hangs forever. Even more weird, if I do `cat file.txt` I can see the content of the file and it is up-to-date as well.

The problem persists even if I close PhpStorm until I restart the Docker daemon itself, rebooting the container is not enough.

As I said this only happens using PhpStorm, if I edit files using *nano* or *VSCode* everything works properly. I also tried an older PhpStorm version (2020.1.4), no success.

A colleague of mine who also works on this project has no problem at all with PhpStorm although he has an older macOS version (Mojave).

### System

I'm using macOS Big Sur 11.2.3 and Docker desktop 3.3.1 (see screenshot).
[image: Docker desktop]

### Conclusion

I tried to play around with Docker settings like file sharing, resources, gRPC, experimental features. I also tried to disable all third-party plugins in PhpStorm and remove `.idea` folder from project. The problem still persists.

Any idea or suggestion would be much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Got it, you need to disable *Back up files before saving*. Unfortunately this option is not project specific so it basically disables backups globally, but at least it works.

In case someone finds a better solution I would appreciate it.

[image: PhpStorm settings]